# Multiple pragmas directives on for loop (C and VS 2013)

Tags: c, visual-studio, optimization, openmp, vectorization

I'm trying to use OpenMP to split a for loop computation to multiple threads. Additionally, I'm trying to instruct the compiler to vectorize each chunk assigned to each thread. The code is the following:

```
#pragma omp for private(i)
__pragma(loop(ivdep))
for (i = 0; i < 4096; i++)
    vC[i] = vA[i] + SCALAR * vB[i];
```

The problem is that both pragmas expect the for loop right after.

**Is there any smart construct to make this work?**

Some might argue that due to the for loop splitting with OpenMP, the vectorization of the loop won't work. However I read that the *#pragma omp for* divides the loop into a number of contiguous chunks equal to the thread count. **Is thitt?**

Answer (score 2):

What about using `#pragma omp for simd private(i)` instead of the pragma + __pragma() ?

Edit: since OpenMP 4 doesn't seem to be an option for you, you can manually split your loop to get rid of the `#pragma omp for` by just computing the index limits by hand using `omp_get_num_threads()` and `omp_get_thread_num()`, and then keep the `ivdep` for the per-thread loop.

Edit 2: since I'm a nice guy and since this is boilerplate (more common when programming in MPI, but still) but quite annoying to get right when you do it for the first time, here is a possible solution:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    int n = 4096;
    int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
    int nth = omp_get_num_threads();
    int chunk = n / nth;
    int beg = tid * chunk + min( tid, n % nth );
    int end = ( tid + 1 ) * chunk + min( tid + 1, n % nth );
    #pragma ivdep
    for ( int i = beg; i < end; i++ ) {
        vC[i] = vA[i] + SCALAR * vB[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: I would but it appears that the VS2013 does not recognize the 'simd' openmp token

Comment: maybe you can try installing/using a more recent compiler, supporting OpenMP 4.0. GCC does, and can be installed with cygwin for example. The Intel compiler does as well and is free for non-commercial use.

Comment: I know the Intel compiler generates better code and I don't need the #pragma loop anymore. However I now have only VS CL and I was hoping for a quick fix.